# How to clean green gunk off case fans?

Tags: cleaning, fan

I just bought a used custom-built computer locally. In the process of checking the hardware, I notice that the case fans have accumulated a lot of green "gunk" and I've tried wetting the edge of a paper towel to wipe and rub it off. Still, there is always some residue remaining. What's the best way to clean off this gunk?

Thanks in advance. No pictures, but I can take some if needed.

Comment: *Green?!* That's a new one...

Comment: Yes... DARK green. I had to spend nearly 2 hours cleaning out the case and other components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rubbing alcohol](http://www.thriftyfun.com/tf457631.tip.html) is an excellent gunk remover, no matter what color.

Comment: Hmmmm... I never thought of that. I'll definitely give that a try.

Comment: My dad suggested Vim first, and it worked for the most part. Used rubbing alcohol after and it's perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use cotton buds to clean the dust off them, it can get right into the corner.

Comment: What are earbud things?

Comment: oops, I meant cotton buds

Comment: like q-tips?  they're kinda like earbuds... i mean, they both go in ears, right?

Comment: Oh, q-tips.... right.

Comment: Good point, but adding some liquid "solution" will make it work even better. I ended up using Vim for the first stage and then some rubbing alcohol and it is squeaky clean! Except that I cracked a corner when screwing it back on. >.<

Comment: yes q-tips (that's American?)